# Cannot build node typescript project with only production dependencies

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have a node typescript project that uses several third party libraries including express. In order to get the types I follow the instructions I find everywhere to install the @types/express module as a dev dependency. Everything works fine when I install my packages using `npm ci` but when I try to follow best practices for building a container image and run `npm ci --only=production` the build fails with the error message.

```
error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '/home/app/node_modules/express/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2.818   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express';`
```

This is obviously because it doesn't have the type library available, but nowhere do I see anyone installing @types packages as a production dependency.

Whats the best practice for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types are necessary for development and build (i.e. transpilation of your TypeScript files into JavaScript).

You install only production dependencies into your "final" image, where you should copy your already built JS files. Hence there should be no longer any types in this stage.

If you still need to build (transpile) your TS files into JS within your container, then consider this stage as still a build phase, hence you still need some development dependencies. Which can then be removed for production.